# What is the "Stock/Equity Ratio"?

Tags: stocks, bonds, stock-valuation, books

I'm reading the Intelligent Investor and I found this:

> 2. Stock/Equity Ratio. This is the ratio of the market price of the junior stock issues* to the total face amount of the debt, or the debt plus preferred stock. It is a rough measure of the protection, or “cushion,” afforded by the presence of a junior investment that must first bear the brunt of unfavorable developments. This factor includes the market’s appraisal of the future prospects of the enterprise.

But then I googled "stock/equity ratio" and can't find anything. **Is there another name for this ratio? Do you know this ratio?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Intelligent Investor was written 73 years ago. Times have changed and the modern equivalent ratio is **debt-to-equity ratio**.

It is essentially 1/(Stock Equity Ratio).

Reference: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/debtequityratio.asp